# Passing a list from user control to window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have User Control in a WPF PRISM project from where on a button click (a command is bound) following function is called:

```
private async void UpdateStoreSet()
        {
            List<ValidationData> failedData = await _adapter.UpdateStoreSetData(this.DataList.Result as List<StoreSetData>);

            if (failedData != null && failedData.Count > 0)
            {
                FailedValidationViewModel objFaliedVM = new FailedValidationViewModel(_errorHandler, _dlgService, failedData);
                //objFaliedVM.DataList = failedData;
                Windows.FailedValidation win = new Windows.FailedValidation(objFaliedVM, _errorHandler);
                win.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
                win.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
                win.ShowDialog();
                //_dlgService.ShowMessageBox(failedData.Count.ToString() + " records failed validation!", "Failure", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Refresh the list
                SearchPlanograms();
            }
        }
```

In the constructor Window View Model, here it is written:

```
public FailedValidationViewModel(IErrorHandlerService inErrorHandler, IDialogService inDlgService, List<ValidationData> lstFailedList)
        {
            // Set dependency injected services to local variables
            _errorHandler = inErrorHandler;            
            _dlgService = inDlgService;

            //Instantiate the failed validation list
            DataList = lstFailedList;

            // Instantiate the command
            this.ExportToExcelCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.ExportToExcel);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public List<ValidationData> DataList
        {
            get
            {
                return _failedValidation;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_failedValidation != value)
                {
                    SetProperty(ref _failedValidation, value);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Following grid is shown in the window:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridFailedFloorplans" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="None"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataList.Result.View}" AutoExpandAllGroups="True" DefaultSorting="Name"                         
            dx:ThemeManager.Theme="Default" Height="350" Width="580">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView AllowGrouping="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowEditing="False" AutoWidth="True" Name="gridFailedValidationTableView"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>            
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="abc" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="def" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="efg" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ghi" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="jkl FixedWidth="True" Width="100" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="mmm" FixedWidth="True" Width="100" />                
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

But grid is coming up as empty with ItemsSource=null. I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Check for binding errors in `Output` window. Does binding to `DataList.Result.View` makes sense?

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext in your window to your VM ?

Comment: Prism or DevExpress ?

Comment: Yes I am binding to DataContext in xaml.cs

Comment: The framework is Prism, the grid control is DevExpress grid control

Comment: DataList.Result could not be found-I am checking what to bind it to exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the binding be

```
<dxg:GridControl ....
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
```

Otherwise its' looking for a property `Result` on the `List<ValidationData>`, which doesn't exist and results in a null `itemsSource`.